# Unexpected token = in node.js for initializing an object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to use an object within node.js javascript to map Telnet commands and options to its integer value:

```
MudSocket = class MudSocket extends TelnetSocket {

    tel = { opt2num: 
        ^ here is the error "unexpected Token"
        { IAC: "255",
          DONT: "254", // and so on
        },}
```

The visual studio code editor is showing no error with this, and I tried :, : Object (Error:only valid for typescript) and a prefix of this.(Error: Unexpected Token again for this).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Instance_properties

Comment: Understood: I have to move it inside the constructor and make it with this. prefix. Thanks for the fast answer. You may post it as answer, or is it so basic, that I should delete it? :-)